# Phase-amplitude decomposition of a wave

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, semiclassical

Consider the stationary Schrodinger equation in 1D:
$$
\psi''(x) + Q(x) \psi(x) = 0 \quad x \in [0, L]
$$
I am specifically interested in the case where $Q(x)$ is monotonic and gives a single turning point at $x_0$ between $0$ and $L$, with an oscillating solution to the left and a tunneling solution to the right:
$$
Q(x) = \begin{cases} 
   |Q(x)| & x < x_0 \\
    0 & x = x_0 \\
    -|Q(x)| & x > x_0
\end{cases}
$$
One approach to this problem is to decompose the wave into its local phase and amplitude
$$
\psi(x) = A(x) \cos S(x)
$$
One reason to do this is that with a judicious choice of anchor point for the phase function, $S(0)$, the amplitude and phase individually vary slowly, whereas the total wave $\psi$ rapidly oscillates in regions where $Q$ is nearly constant. This can be nice for numerical solutions of the wave equation.

However, I am considering the reverse situation. Suppose I have obtained a numerical solution for the total wave $\psi$, is it possible to unambiguously determine the functions $A$ and $S$, ideally in such a way that the phase and amplitude are slowly varying?

It is not clear to me that this is possible in general. For example, take
$$
Q(x) = \begin{cases} 
 1 & x < 0 \\
1 - x/x_0 & x > 0
\end{cases}
$$
In this case, the wave on $[0, L]$ is an Airy function, whose amplitude is determined by matching to the free-space solution at $x=0$. One can identify well-defined phases and amplitudes for the the Airy function asymptotically via WKB, but it's not clear if that idea carries over through the turning point.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking if it is possible to find *analytic* expression for $A$ and $S$ given a numerical complex solution? If not then I am not sure I understand the question; at each $x$ your $\psi(x)$ is a given complex number $z$. A complex number certainly has a unique modulus $|z|$, and a phase that is unique modulo $2\pi$...

Comment: Yes, I think you understand correctly. For instance, given the free-space wave function $a \cos(k x + \theta)$, I would identify $A(x)= a$ as the amplitude and $S(x) = kx+\theta$ as the phase function. I am seeking a continuation of these amplitude and phase functions into the region with nonzero potential, given tabulated values of $\psi$ there. I think the mention of a complex-valued $\psi$ is unnecessarily muddling my question, so I have edited to make everything real-valued.

Comment: Is your question as general as this one: "Given an oscillatory function $\psi(x) \in \mathbb{R}$, can one uniquely identify its envelope $A(x) \in \mathbb{R}$?"? Or, do you expect us to use the information that $\psi(x)$ follows the time-independent Schroedinger equation (and perhaps with a particular potential)?

Comment: @norio The fact that $\psi(x)$ solves the TDSE is valid information to use, and I suspect it is essential to making a unique connection between $\psi(x)$ and $A(x)$. As for the potential, I am interested in the case where there is exactly one turning point.

Answer (score 0):

In Physical Review 35, 863 (1930), W.E. Milne addressed writing Schrodinger's Equation in terms of amplitude and phase instead of the wave function.  I recommend searching for "Milne's Equation" with your favorite search engine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).